# How to convert timestamp to seconds with timezone in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9.3

Why ruby doesn't subtract Timezone when I convert timestamp to seconds?

```
1.9.3-p429 :008 > a = Time.now()
  => 2013-09-27 16:23:17 +0300 
1.9.3-p429 :011 > a.utc
  => 2013-09-27 13:23:17 UTC
1.9.3-p429 :009 > a.to_i
  => 1380288197 
1.9.3-p429 :010 > a.utc.to_i
  => 1380288197
```

a.to_i should be 3 hours (10800 seconds) higher than a.utc.to_i and I need it to be, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the thing about `Time` in Ruby. `Time.now.to_f` gives you the [number of seconds since the Epoch.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Time.html#method-i-to_f) More info about the Epoch is [available on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29)

To get a difference between two `Time` objects, you should just subtract them to get the `difference`, as [noted in the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Time.html#2D-method).

To get the difference between two of objects that hold the same time, but are of different UTC offsets (as seen in your question), simply use the `utc_offset` method.

```
a = Time.now
b = Time.now.utc

difference = (b.utc_offset - a.utc_offset)/60/60
#=> 5
```

Comment: Yes [Time#utc_offset](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Time.html#method-i-utc_offset) is the one we need to think of here..

Answer (score 0):

The time doesn't change, it's just adjusted to a different time zone:

```
a = Time.now    #=> 2013-09-27 16:01:51 +0200
b = a.dup.utc   #=> 2013-09-27 14:01:51 UTC

a == b          #=> true
```